# Email verification flutter firebase exception

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here's my home_view.dart file
[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxg42.png) [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEZIS.png)

I'm getting an exception... And here it is...

[image: Exception]

Help me to how to do email verification.

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet

Comment: Now you can see right?

Comment: It is necessary to provide code-snippet that will reproduce the issue, also don't use code-image, You can include some description and you will be able to attached code-snippet, anyway test my method

Comment: Yes but when I tried to post my code doesn't; allow me...It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details... sending this msg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `addPostFrameCallback`

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
  Navigator.of(context)...
});
```